# Displaying linked data source as Sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

As titled,

Is this possible?

I have created a linked data source, which is a combination of more than 5 SP lists, and i've created a dataview sheet using the linked data source. But what i actually want is to display it as a Sharepoint list, so that i can have the ability to perform things on it, especially to export it out as excel.

Is there a way i can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can make custom list, from  colums of your lists(dataview columns), and add there ListItems.
`SPList myCustomList = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["Custom List"];`
`SPListItem myListItem = myList.Items.Add();`
 
`myListItem["Column 1"] = "value 1";`
`myListItem["Column 2"] = "value 2";`
`myListItem["Column 3"] = "value 3";`

Comment: So what you're saying was that, after i created the dataview, i grabbed the data from each column in the dataview using SPServices plugin, and i feed it onto a new SP list?

Comment: You can create list for combination of more than 5 SP lists. Then You can add list items in Your new list from combination of more than 5 SP lists, using visual web part.

Comment: I'm not sure if i'm getting you here. Sorry, but can you please elaborate it further? I'm not sure i'm getting the visual webpart part..